# jquery popup with django

Tags: jquery, django, popup

I dont know much javascript so I wanna achieve this using just django.
problem is,
When working with django popups, I realized, I have to populate 1 popup for all the list items.
imagine u have list items all linked like this.

```
sale/01_0001_02
sale/01_0002_02
sale/01_0003_02
```

How I can create popup menus for each item, linking them individually like

```
sale/01_0001_02/confirm
sale/01_0001_02/reject
sale/01_0001_02/cancel ...

sale/01_0002_02/confirm
sale/01_0002_02/reject
sale/01_0002_02/cancel ...

sale/01_0003_02/confirm
sale/01_0003_02/reject
sale/01_0003_02/cancel ...
```

populating all this popups is possible, but it seems a rather bad possibility.
thx.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the best approach to do this is by sending the json object to the client browser and using their javascript logic to display images. There are built in javascript plugins like [Lightbox](http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/) and [Fancybox](http://fancybox.net). You can use them.

Thanks